# Extract list of list item and split a string from that element in DART

Tags: list, dart, substring, sublist

i have a json data like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "iname": "goa",
        "aa": [
            {
                "period": "Jan 2020",
                "steps": 49,
                "ctr": 09
            },
            {
                "period": "Feb 2020",
                "steps": 44,
                "ctr": 56
            },
            {
                "period": "Mar 2020",
                "steps": 59,
                "ctr": 29
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Now i need to use **period** to draw a line chart by splitting it as Jan, Feb, Mar only
i need a function to split the **period** and extract only jan feb mar  and **store it in integer like 1 for jan, 2 for feb, etc... and use that integer value to classify and plot** line chart for **ctr** points

i tried **substring**,**sublist**,**index of** functions but i am confused about how to form that function

Please kindly help me with it

Answer (score 0):

So you want to extract the month abbreviation, as lower-case, and the `ctr` value for each month. You can create a map of those as, for example:

```dart
var monthCtr = <String, int>{
    for (var aa in jsonData[0]["aa"]) 
        aa["period"].substring(0, 3).toLowerCase() : aa["ctr"] 
};
```

If that's not the format you need, I hope it shows the general approach.